# Get EnhancedR working to send text from Sublime to screen

Tags: r, ubuntu

I want to use Sublime and enhancedR to send my R-code line-by-line to the terminal (ubuntu 12.04)
I have enhancedR installed and set the correct path to screen and R.
However, I just cannot send code from sublime to a terminal where I started R within a screen.

I have toggled with the R application switch to 'screen' and check the path,
everything seems to be allright.
Yet, sending code does not work.
What do I make wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to send R code from sublime to the shell (screen) via the package SendText (rather than EnhancedR).
Just install the package SendText and set the correct path to screen.
That's it. Works perfect.